# MPI - execute program on more than one computer

Tags: c, networking, mpi, distributed-computing, hosts

I'm trying to execute a mpi program on two computers.

First computer: 192.168.0.101

Second computer: 192.168.0.100

I can execute more processes on a single computer, but when I try to do something like this (I'm using command prompt on 192.168.0.101):

```
mpiexec -hosts -2 192.168.0.100 192.168.0.101 "\\192.168.0.101\temp\mpi.exe"
```

I get some errors like: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

However, this execute fine:

```
mpiexec -hosts -2 192.168.0.100 192.168.0.100 "\\192.168.0.101\temp\mpi.exe"
```

How can I execute it on both machines?

Comment: It looks like firewall to me or not listening on the other side

Answer (score 1):

It fails not because of the MPI command, but because the node with address 192.168.0.101 is not configured as it should, so that your program can access it.

First try to ping the node, and then try to solve that issue; to make that node reachable. Your MPI command is fine, that's why it runs fine with the same node twice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured how MPI is supposed to run the process on the remote node ?

typically you have to [configure a remote agent](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=rsh) ( could be ssh, rsh, or other ),